# Collide detection and masks in python 3.2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, collision-detection, pygame

Me and my friend are currently trying to make a game. In this game we wish to have nice collision detection. But we cannot seem to find the way to update the masks in the definiton while loop. :S We have tested it alot of times, with different values and even some really unlogical stuff.

Each time we move the player, the game crashes when it collides with the mask. Its like the loop goes on forever, even though the player and the bush should be going away from eachother when we move the mask and the background.

```
def check_collision():
    while pygame.sprite.collide_mask(player, rock):
       bg.x -= 1 #the x-value of the background
       rock.x -=1 #the x-value of the object
```

- This is just collision when going left using the button "a".
- We also move the background and all the sprites instead of the player.
- We need to use masks.
- We know that it checks the collision, but the mask wont update after bg.x and rock.x are changed.
- We assume that this is because the images aren't moved on the screen. And therefore we have tried putting a blit inside the while loop. It still would not work.

Thank you for helping, and a final question, is there any way to manually move a mask/object?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, collision detection using masks is very time-intensive. Whether or not your game has entered an infinite loop, the processing requirements of a bitmask-bitmask overlap check will make your game run far too slowly.

A simple optimization exists, however:

Any object which is able to collide with things must have some maximum size -- that is, you can find a rectangle which will always contain your player, and your boulder can fit inside another. Therefore, if your player's box doesn't collide with the boulder's box, they can't possibly overlap. Since you insist on collision masking, (which can add some realism to any pixelart game), you can compute the per-pixel collision whenever (and *only* whenever) the bounding boxes collide.

Now, on to your coding style: >:O

It is never a good idea to put a potentially *infinite* loop within a function which should ideally compute an *instant* collision check. In the best-case scenario (which is certainly achievable), you would have one function to check whether two objects collide, and tell you some more useful information (the position of one relative to the other, etcetera); while a separate method of every moving object would fix the collisions.

This would translate to something like:

```
class CollidingObject:
    #This class controls an object which can move and fix collisions

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0 #add relevant initialization code here
        self.y = 0
        self.xVel = 0 # X and Y velocity (for movement)
        self.yVel = 0
        self.xSize = 0 # the width of the object in pixels
        self.ySize = 0 # the height of the object in pixels

    def iscolliding(self, other):
        # using x and y as the center of the object, 
        # this returns an empty tuple if  they don't collide
        if ((self.xSize + other.xSize) / 2 <= abs(self.x - other.x)) and 
           ((self.ySize + other.ySize) / 2 <= abs(self.y - other.y)): return ()
        """ 
        use pygame collidemask here to compute whether they collide.
        if they do, return a vector of 'other's' position relative to self.
        (this can be used to decide how to separate the objects)
        """

    def restitute(self, overlaps_with, distances):
        """
        Given some objects which overlap, and a list of 2D vectors of their 
        relative distances, this separates them however much you like.
        """
        pass
```

As to where your colision checking is done, that depends upon your implementation of object management basics. I will heretofore assume that all of your in-game objects are contained within an iterable; and that on every frame you iterate through your objects, once to render, once to move them -- a structure something like this:

```
while NOT_QUIT:

    for object in objects:
        object.draw_to_screen()
        object.move() # moves the object -- collisions, etc in here

    event_handling_stuff() # handles events
```

In this case, every object can compute collision checking for anything which follows it in *objects*. In doing so, each object can collect how far it has to move from each. Afterwards, each object can move to be as far from each collider as possible.

In a few games I've written, I'd make objects move farther apart the more overlapped they are, giving collisions an elastic quality which makes even very rough restitution algorithms look very sexy. Generally, you can tinker with constants once you have a working check going and that would be the least of your worries.

Hopefully this will have helped you two a little (I realize now I went off a bit on a tangent, but you were asking about how to do the wrong things more efficiently :P).

**tl;dr:** Don't try to fix collisions within your collision check function. Instead, separate it into one which finds all collisions to other objects, and another which fixes all collisions for an object at the same time. 
Add other questions and I'll update (:.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Expanding here on the `"vector of other to self"` bit (which was explained a tad crudely:/)

Generally when two objects collide in real life, they bounce back somewhat in the direction they came from (when you drop a rubber bouncy ball on the floor, it bounces back from whence it came -- it doesn't just phaze through the floor). In most programming applications, you'd want to make bouncy balls (and other colliding things) behave in the same way (well, sometimes you might *want* the ball to phaze though the floor, but that's even easier than bouncing IMHO :P).

To know which way an object must bounce back, you have to know the direction from which it came. More strictly, you have to know the angle at which it collided. This is very easily found if you compare the distance and direction between the centers of each object during the collision. This will provide a pretty accurate representation of two objects bouncing, if the centers you are using are close enough to their centers of mass (in most games the middle of an object is an easy and good approximation).

So, since we don't need to worry about center of mass and all that, we just measure the vector distance between object positions:

```
#Continuing the previous example, we put some code like this in 'iscolliding' :)
if they collide (pygame mask stuff) :
    x_distance = self.x - other.x
    y_distance = self.y - other.y
    return (x_distance, y_distance)
```

This code can give you the line along which each object should move to resolve the collision as fast as possible. The rest is a matter of accelerating each object along this line, making sure they don't go closer together (pay attention to signs), and tweaking constants to create a realistic effect.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much! This has been helping us alot!

But we still have some questions. :)

Let me come back to you! We are trying to work it out :)

Comment: We are wondering how we can return a vector of 'other's' position relative to self?

Comment: Please help us :) We really dont get the part:

""" 
        use pygame collidemask here to compute whether they collide.
        if they do, return a vector of 'other's' position relative to self.
        (this can be used to decide how to separate the objects)
        """

Comment: @AimEffect Oh, sorry for the delay -- The idea behind getting a vector of "the other object's position relative to your own" (paraphrasing here) will tell you which of your two colliding objects is farther up, and which is farther to the right. Knowing this will tell you which direction each object should move to fix the collision. I'll update my answer with explanation, best wishes (: